# Error" function not declared " for simple chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(function(){
    $('#alias').keyup(function(){
        $('#youtuber').html($('#alias').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Julius extension</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Find your YouTuber: <span id="youtuber"></span> </h3>
    <input id="alias" placeholder="Search your youtuber"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to code a simple chrome extension. Right now I want that everything I write in the search bar of my template gets displayed above, after the "Find your YouTuber:" text. 
However, for some reason that is not the case, I get the error message: `popup.js:1 (anonymous function)`, whilst running the extension.

popuph.html :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Julius extension</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
      body{
          width: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Find your YouTuber: <span id="youtuber"></span> </h3>
    <input id="alias" placeholder="Search your youtuber"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#alias').keyup(function () {
    $('#youtuber').html($('#alias').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to link to jQuery with an absolute URL. Stackoverflow isn't hosting a version at the URL you put in your live demo.

Comment: is that script tag actually at the top of your page or is that just added in the snippet?

Comment: It is just added in the snippet